# Completed forms stay on phone even if CommCare sense is enabled

Tags: commcare

Why do some completed forms remain on the phone, even if CommCare Sense is activated? (screenshot below for reference)

[image: screen shot]

For additional information, it doesn't appear that this is controlled by the 'Saved Form' section of the Android settings. I have included a link [here](https://www.commcarehq.org/a/champ-cameroon/apps/view/817f920b76b14e649b217ccee36982d4/) to how the app is currently set-up on HQ for reference. You'll note that CommCare Sense is enabled, which should automatically disable the saved form settings.

(Unfortunately my internet is too weak to actually send along the screenshot!)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behavior is that enabling CommCare sense mode automatically sets the "Days for Review" setting to "Forms are Never Removed" (which you can see is indicated in the settings UI on HQ when you have sense mode enabled). This is why your completed forms are staying on the phone. Besides this 1 setting, sense mode doesn't affect anything on Android, which is why it's under the "Java Phone User Interface Settings" header.

More generally, the most important takeaway here is that **"sense mode" is intended to be used on java phones, only**. For Android devices, if you would like to control whether incomplete/saved forms show up, and how long form records stay on the device, you should disable sense mode and then configure each of those settings yourself (all 3 are available under the "Android Settings" header).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the ability to access completed forms is controlled by the "Saved Forms" setting in the application which can be found under "Android Settings". See the screenshot below for how to disable this functionality.

[image: disable saved forms]

Comment: Thanks, @Cory, for your note. I'm not sure that this fully resolves the problem. Let me know if the additional details I provided in my message above help clarify!

Comment: Does @Aliza Stone 's answer help?